# SharePoint 2010 farm performance degradation

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, azure, sharepoint-2010

Developing within SharePoint 2010 - all the latest updates for it are installed (SP2 etc.)

Standard farm with 2 application servers, 2 front-end servers, Active Directory server and 2 SQL servers. All this stuff is hosted by Windows Azure Virtual machines, within Virtual network.

While performing simple `SPWebApplication.Lookup()` noticed that it takes very-very long to complete - about 16 seconds. To compare - locally it takes about 1 second. And on another very similar farm, also hosted in Azure - about 2 seconds.

What attempts were made to fix performance degradation:

1. Checked configs and network settings, pings etc. - looks 100% OK.
2. Profiled with SQL Profiler - no bottlenecks found -  there is no hard SQL for this request actually.
3. Double-check that all the servers and DBs are upgraded and up to date.
4. Kick off all the possible errors that were found in ULS and Windows logs - now it's clear there.
5. Investigation of metrics with Metalogix Diagnostics manager - as result nothing critical was found. It only sometimes showed that processor queue length is big. But as I know, normal number for it is #of cores +1. So 4-5 in my case is fine. Also it's needed to note that from my perspective - for VM it's also normal to have such number.
6. Wrote very simple console app that performs lookup of web app. Profiled with Ants profiler. Noticed that call tree differs from the result received locally. Maybe that's OK, cause locally I have standalone installation. 
   The result at farm is not optimistic - several calls have a huge Hits count. Though, it's clear where the bottleneck in the call tree - all the ideas about the source have already finished. Profiling result as follows: http://1drv.ms/1kYT3rT

It would be great if you could advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the size of config db?

Comment: 3 DBs: 11.5GBs, 1.5GBs and 40MBs - which is actually fine. Best practice for one content DB size is about 100GBs. Looking ant profiler call tree - it doesn't look like a SQL issue.

Comment: I meant sharepoint config database not content database. It has name something like "SharePoint_Config". I had issues with it before when timerjob history table became huge.

Comment: Oh, sorry - mismatched. It's about 500MBs.

Answer (score 0):

How many disks do you have on your VM?

Azure has limited IOPS, 500 per disk... organise your databases so they are on different disks to get more IOPS. You can have 16 disks per VM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn248436.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I know this. And SQL has 4 separate discs at this env right now. I could agree with such theory but one lookup is not a big deal and cannot create big workload. Also would like to note that similar environment, only with one disc for SQL - performs lookup within 1-2 seconds.